# How to remove n_fmt after progress done

Tags: python, tqdm

To me, the process should only be expressed as a percentage.
But when this process is over, another process begins.

```
Loading-'|          |125/?'
Loading-'|          |150/?'
Loading-'|          |175/?'
Loading-'|          |225/?'
```

How can I remove this?

My code:

```
with tqdm(total=100, bar_format="Loading-'{l_bar}{bar}|{n_fmt}/{total_fmt}'") as progressbar:
    for i in range(10):
        # function
        progressbar.update(25)
```

Comment: You're looping up to 10 iterations, but you're increasing the progressbar by 25 each time. 25 * 10 =  250. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I need a loop, I use it to edit the message. For Telegram bot.

Comment: Is there no other way?